# List of tcolorboxes in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, tcolorbox

For a tutorial presented with LaTeX Beamer slides I want to add a list of all the tasks inside it. The tasks are set as individual `tcolorbox`es, so I like to use the `list inside` key, which automatically creates the list of boxes.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with Beamer, as it wouldn't compile.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[list inside=tsks]{plainbox}[1]{colback=blue!10, title=#1}
\begin{document}
    \section{Slides}
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents
        \begin{plainbox}{One}
            First box
        \end{plainbox}
    \end{frame}
    \section{Overview}
    \begin{frame}
        \tcblistof[\section*]{tsks}{List of Tasks}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem appears to be related to what the ToC file of `list inside`, here `.tsks`, is filled with. I think it includes macros which are not available in Beamer. When comparing the file with Beamer's `.toc` file it looks distinctly different (and more like the `.toc` file of a usual LaTeX document would look like).

Eventually I'd like to have a list of tasks styled like Beamer's ToC, i.e. without any dotted lines or page numbers, but with links to the tasks.

Answer (score 4):

You could redefine `\numberline` and style the list as you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[list inside=tsks]{plainbox}[1]{colback=blue!10, title=#1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[2]{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section in toc}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in toc}%
    #2%
    \par\vfill%
}

\renewcommand*\l@tcolorbox{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Slides}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{plainbox}{One}
        First box
    \end{plainbox}
    \begin{plainbox}{Two}
        First box
    \end{plainbox}
    \begin{plainbox}{Three}
        First box
    \end{plainbox}
\end{frame}

\section{Overview}

\begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \tcblistof[\section*]{tsks}{List of Tasks}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks perfect! Does redefining `\numberline` have any side-effects? I grepped through Beamer's code base and apparently the macro is not used anywhere – so it seems to be fine!

Comment: @AndiH No guarantee, one never knows with such hacks :)

Comment: Ok, I'm investigating! For my proper set of slides there's a compilation error – while it works for my test case. Could you, by chance, add links to the entries of the list of boxes?

Comment: @AndiH I guess links are a separate problem.

Comment: @AndiH What does the error say?

Comment: I found it. I used `\textbf{}` (as in `\begin{plainbox}{\textbf{One}}`) which apparently breaks things. I can work around that. – The error was `! Argument of \XC@col@rlet has an extra }.`…

Comment: @AndiH Makes sense - never put formatting instructions in arguments.

Comment: @AndiH If you want bold titles, use `\newtcolorbox[list inside=tsks]{plainbox}[1]{colback=blue!10, title=#1,fonttitle=\bfseries}`

Comment: Ah, that's a great hint! I was about to add it like `title={\textbf{Task}: #1}`. You think that adding links is possible at all?

Comment: @AndiH yes it is certainly possible, but I don't know if tcolorboxes automatically set a link target or if one has to come up with some way to create unique target names.